# Remove specific substring from string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I would like to remove smiley from message. I've defined smiley with this tags `<sml/>` and absolutely I gave specific number for each of them..like `<sml1/>`, `<sml2/>` ,..., `<sml30/>`. it can be sub string of specific string like :

Here is messages `<sml4/>`

or
Here `<sml4/>` is messages.

or
`<sml4/>` Here is messages.

I want to remove this tag from message. and result will be :
*Here is messages.*

```
std::string receivedMessage = msg.body();
    if (receivedMessage.find("<sml") != std::string::npos && receivedMessage.find("/>") != std::string::npos)
    {
       for(int i=0 ; i<=30 ; ++i)
        receivedMessage = receivedMessage.remove ("<sml".i."/>")
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The code snippet does not look like C. What is the purpose of that, please ?

Comment: remove <sml4/> from string

Comment: You can write a regex for capturing those smilies.

Comment: I find them with receivedMessage.find("<sml") but i don't know how to remove them @AmitTiwari

Comment: See this link: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch04s12.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a regular expression for example if your compiler does not support them you can do the task as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    for ( std::string s : { "Here is messages <sml4/>", "Here <sml4/> is messages", "<sml4/> Here is messages" } )
    {
        const char start[] = "<sml";
        const char end[]   = "/>";
        const size_t l = sizeof( end );

        std::string::size_type n1, n2;

        if ( ( n1 = s.find( start ) ) != std::string::npos && 
             ( n2 = s.find( end, n1 ) ) != std::string::npos ) 
        {
            n2 += l - 1;
            if ( n2 != s.size() && std::isblank( ( unsigned char )s[n2] ) ) ++n2;
            else if ( n1 != 0 && std::isblank( ( unsigned char )s[n1-1] ) ) --n1;

            std::cout << s << std::endl;
            s.erase( n1, n2 - n1 );                     
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }                     
}
```

The program output looks like

```
Here is messages <sml4/>
Here is messages

Here <sml4/> is messages
Here is messages

<sml4/> Here is messages
Here is messages
```

Also for simplicity the calls of function `std::isblank` you can substitute for the following comparisons

```
            if ( n2 != s.size() && s[n2] == ' ' ) ++n2;
            else if ( n1 != 0 && s[n1-1] == ' ' ) --n1;
```

Answer (score 2):

With C++ 11, assuming you have:

```
string message = R"Here is messages <sml4/>";
```

You may write a simple [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (as already suggested by [Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400318/c-remove-specific-substring-from-string/31400690#comment50775681_31400318) in comments). To put it in code:

```
string messageWithoutSmiles = regex_replace(message,
    regex(R"<\s*sml\d+\s*\/\s*>"), "");
```

Regex is pretty simple but a little explanation may help:

- `<\s*` <kbd><</kbd> character followed by zero or more white spaces.
- `sml` literal string.
- `\d+` followed by one or more digits (equivalent to `[0-9]`).
- `\s*` followd by zero or more white spaces.
- `\/\s*` <kbd>/</kbd> character followd by zero or more white spaces.
- `>` closing <kbd>></kbd>.

If C++ 11 is not an option (!) and you're already using [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) then you have an equivalent regex tool. Just *for fun* you may also manually implement something similar (without white space to simplify code and far away to be optimal from performance POV, to handle white spaces just add more `.find()` splitting token in atomic units <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>sml</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, maybe with an handy helper function):

```
while (true) {
    const string::size_type n1 = message.find("<sml", 0);
    if (n1 == string::npos)
       break;

    const string::size_type n2 = message.find("/>", n1);
    if (n2 == string::npos)
       break;

    message = message.erase(n1, n2 - n1 + 2);
}
```

<sub>Note: code isn't *optimal* and it's not even *nice* (it should be encapsulated in a function and you wouldn't use `while (true)` in real life) but its purpose is to be *illustrative* (then easy to read and understand), not ready-to-use.</sub>

Comment: @afn: this is what I was talking about.

Comment: @AmitTiwari sorry, I saw your comment after posting. I added link back in my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string message = "Here is messages < sml4/> ";             
std::size_t found =  message.find("< sml4/> ");

if (found!=std::string::npos)
{                                                     
 message.erase(found,found+sizeof("< sml4/> ")); 

}
```